How can I get a duplicate key error if the row does not match the predicate of the unique index?
I'm using Postgres v16. I've got a unique index on my invoice table:
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_invoice_display_id 
ON invoice (tenant_id, display_id, expiry_timestamp) 
WHERE id = original_invoice_id;

# \d unq_invoice_display_id
                Index "public.unq_invoice_display_id"
      Column      |          Type          | Key? |    Definition    
------------------+------------------------+------+------------------
 tenant_id        | bigint                 | yes  | tenant_id
 display_id       | character varying(255) | yes  | display_id
 expiry_timestamp | bigint                 | yes  | expiry_timestamp
unique, btree, for table "public.invoice", predicate (id = original_invoice_id)

Note the predicate on the index: predicate (id = original_invoice_id).
When I'm inserting a row I get a duplicate key error. However, the row I'm inserting does not have equal values in id and original_invoice_id.
insert into invoice (...,original_invoice_id,...,id) values (..,13484,...,13553);
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unq_invoice_display_id"
DETAIL:  Key (tenant_id, display_id, expiry_timestamp)=(902, 758107, 253402214400000) already exists.

I know that the unq_invoice_display_id index causing the problem, because when I drop the index, the insert goes through.
Am I misunderstanding something? I don't understand how inserting a row that does not match the predicate can cause a duplicate key error on the index.

I cannot reproduce your error:  https://dbfiddle.uk/_281XgoO

Please post complete table definition (ddl) and complete insert statement (no ...).

I figured out the issue was caused by a trigger on the table:
CREATE FUNCTION invoice_set_original_id()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.revision = '0' THEN
    NEW.original_invoice_id := NEW.id;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

The values I thought I was inserting changed after the insert statement so that the row did violate the unique index in a way that clearly makes sense.
I figured this out by dropping columns one by one and attempting to insert the problematic data until I saw this error:
ERROR:  record "new" has no field "revision"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function invoice_set_original_id() line 3 at IF

This clued me in that I should look at the invoice_set_original_id function to see what it's doing.
